# Call Ruby method in module Foo from Foo::MyClass

Tags: ruby

What is the preferred way to call a method in a Ruby class, that lives in it's parent module?

like this..

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

module Foo
    def baz
        123123
    end
    
    class Bar 
        def test
            puts baz
        end
    end
    
    class Bar
    end
end

bar = Foo::Bar.new
bar.test
```

I can get this to work if I do this..

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

module Foo
    def baz
        123123
    end
    
    class Bar 
        include Foo
        def test
            puts baz
        end
    end
    
    class Bar
    end
end

bar = Foo::Bar.new
bar.test
```

But is this the best way?

Comment: What is "good" or "bad" is a matter of opinion, and questions asking for opinions are off-topic on [so]. Please, provide a precise, unambiguous, objectively measurable metric, how to determine what is "the best way".

Comment: Just as an example of *why* it is important that you provide *your specific* metric, I can tell you that, according to *my specific* metric, the whole code doesn't make sense, and should be redesigned from the ground up. But that's probably not the answer you are looking for, which is why you need to tell us what criteria *you* use to determine "bestness".

Comment: `include` is the correct way to include instance methods from a module. But including the parent module doesn't seem quit right. You should put `baz` into a separate module (e.g. `Foo::Utils`) and include that one.

Comment: Didn't frame it as good / bad.  There are tradeoffs with everything, especially with a lang as flexible as Ruby. If there are tradeoffs with certain approaches perhaps you could enlighten me :) @JörgWMittag

Comment: @GN.: Your question is "But is this the best way?" This question can only be answered if you tell us how you measure "best", otherwise the question is meaningless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
module Foo
  def self.baz
    123123
  end

  class Bar
    def test
      puts Foo.baz
    end
  end
end

bar = Foo::Bar.new
bar.test
```

Comment: Although this works, you should some explanation.

Comment: my approach is better if you need specific methods (not all) from a module (your example). But if a module implements some abstract logic that needs inside a class and state of the class instance needs inside the module's methods then your approach is better.